# How to add alternating (book) indentation into an existing pdf?

Tags: pdf, indentation, pdfpages, printing

I have my own latex script and I need to add an already existing .pdf file, but I need it in the printing form (my latex document class has the `twoside` parameter).

I am using the **pdfpages** package, so I can import my pdf with:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{test.pdf}
```

But with this solution there is no indendation (no one-sided, nor two-sided). How do I add it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have actually found an answer in the **pdfpages** [package documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfpages.pdf/0).

The solution is to add the `offset` parameter into the function like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=-, offset=1cm 0]{test.pdf}
```

Where the parameter values are defined as follows `offset=<offsetX> <offsetY>`.